# python re.sub ignoring hyphens without removing them from the output

Tags: python-3.x, regex, substitution

I want to match numerals written as words and substitute those words for their equivalent in numbers.

Simplified examples:

I have a CSV file that contains:

```
twenty-two\t22
seventy-two thousand\t72000
etc.
```

And in my text, I can have the numbers written with or without hyphens. So what I'm trying to do is match the words ignoring the hyphens but I don't want to delete all hyphens from the text (in case there are hyphens somewhere else in other words of the text).

```
An off-campus apartment that costs seventy-two thousand dollars.
=> An off-campus apartment that costs 72000 dollars.
An off-campus apartment that costs seventy two thousand dollars.
=> An off-campus apartment that costs 72000 dollars.
```

My code:

```
def transform(line,file):
    
    listfile = []
    with open(file,"r") as rscf :
        read_ressource = csv.reader(rscf, delimiter="\t")
        for row in read_ressource :
            listfile.append(row)

        dictRessource =  {str(rows[0]):str(rows[1]) for rows in listfile}
    
    regex = "|".join([rf"\b{x}\b(?!((\s?\b\d\b\s?)|(\s?(hundred|thousand|mille|milliard|million|billion|trillion))?(\s?\(?\d?{y}\)?)))" for x,y in dictRessource.items()])  
    return re.sub(f'{regex}', lambda match: dictRessource[str.lower(match.group(0))], line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

What I tried so far:

```
def transform(line,file):
    pattern = re.compile("-")
    listfile = []
    with open(file,"r") as rscf :
        read_ressource = csv.reader(rscf, delimiter="\t")
        for row in read_ressource :
            listfile.append(row)
            
        dictRessourcesWith =  {str(rows[0]):str(rows[1]) for rows in listfile}
        dictRessourcesSans = {pattern.sub(' ',str(rows[0])):str(rows[1]) for rows in listfile}
    
    dictRessource = {**dictRessourcesWith, **dictRessourcesSans}

    
    regex = "|".join([rf"\b{x}\b(?!((\s?\b\d\b\s?)|(\s?(hundred|thousand|mille|milliard|million|billion|trillion))?(\s?\(?\d?{y}\)?)))" for x,y in dictRessource.items()])  
    return re.sub(f'{regex}', lambda match: dictRessource[str.lower(match.group(0))], line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

But because I'm working with very large text files, I'm looking for a way to do this by straight-up ignoring hyphens from the start without having to create a larger regex that makes the process take even longer.

Thank you

Comment: It seems you need to replace `-` with `[-\s]`, that is, replace `{x}` with `{x.replace('-', r'[-\s]')}` and replace `{y}` with `{y.replace('-', r'[-\s]')}` in your `regex` variable.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. The "x" and the "y" are the key/value of my dictionary (word/number). Not sure why I need to replace the "-" in {y}.

Comment: Right, no need to do it with `y`, sorry. But it should work with `x`. You just need to make sure the key is correct when searching for the right value, `match.group().replace(" ", "")` or something like that instead of `str.lower(match.group(0))`

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but this is still not working for me. If I do dict[match.group(0).replace("-", " ")] or , dict[match.group(0)].replace("-", " ") I get a key error for the keys that are one word like "one" or "two". And if I do (adict[match.group(0)]).replace("-", " "), It doesn't work.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SVZJ7j

Answer (score 1):

Your regex data is coming with a hyphen, and your text can come with *either* `-` or a space in between numeral parts. That means, you need to match texts with a `[- ]` or `[-\s]` pattern instead of a mere hyphen.

When building the dictionary, you can keep on using lowercased `rows[1]` data with hyphens, but when matching, you need to replace `-` with `[- ]` / `[-\s]`.

A [sample code snippet](https://ideone.com/FpAsSB) could look like

```py
import re

file_text = 'twenty-two\t22\nseventy-two thousand\t72000'
listfile = [x.split('\t') for x in file_text.splitlines()]
dictRessource = {str(rows[0]):str(rows[1]) for rows in listfile}
regex = re.compile( "|".join([r"\b{}\b(?!((\s?\b\d\b\s?)|(\s?(hundred|thousand|mille|milliard|million|billion|trillion))?(\s?\(?\d?{}\)?)))".format(x.replace('-', r'[\s-]'), y) for x,y in dictRessource.items()]) , re.I)
    
def transform(line):
    return regex.sub(lambda match: dictRessource[match.group(0).lower().replace(' ', '-')], line) 
    
print( transform("Some tWenty-two things and twEnty two ...") )
# => Some 22 things and 22 ...
```